# Task scheduler not writing logs to specified location for log4net

Tags: c#, task, log4net, scheduler

Log4net doesn't write to text file at specific location from task scheduler . But while running the exe it is able to do so.
Any help is appreciated

Expectation to log files in specific folder using task scheduler . Also tried using start in optional property but not sure which path to be executed

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. What user is Task Scheduler using to run the task? What happens when Task Scheduler runs the task? Do you have Task History enabled?